# How to calculate percentage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, percentage

I am coding an aim-trainer, the user can either hit or miss the circle.

I want to calculate the average % of the hit/misses.

So, for example the user:

hits: 6 times
&
misses: 3 times

the percentage is 50%.

I want it in that format 100%, 70%, 60% yeah you get it...

But how do I get that far by doing a calculation?

[image: Displaying results]

Comment: What did u try ? Please share your code try

Comment: Divide hits by hits+misses, multiply by 100.

Comment: @Barmar, it's 2AM, been coding whole day, no need to put people down, thanks.

Comment: sorry about that.

Comment: if total tries are total hits then [(total hits - total miss) x 100 ] / total hits .. if total tries are (hit+miss) then (total hits x 100) / (total hits + total miss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what is changing the values of hits and misses field.

Whenever there is a change in any of those fields, do `percentage = (hits/(hits+misses)) *100` to get the percentage.  (I see you are doing `(misses/hits)*100` in your example)

Also, take care in rounding off the percentage using `percentage.toFixed(2)` or `Math.round(percentage)` as mentioned by Chris in another answer and add the `%` sign after it or in the name of the field.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got it working this way, perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use Math.round() for show two decimal

```
Math.round(3*100/6) // misses * 100 / hits
```

Comment: I think its the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for editing! I missed `Math.round` in my answer! :(

Comment: I have tested several cases and forgot to change, thanks for the observation

Comment: you gave a more detailed description. good point

Comment: I got the answer accepted and because I used your answer as reference, I am upvoting!